# Export Functionality in Tapestry 4

Tags: tapestry

I need to develop a export functionality on click of button so that I can export the viewed HTML page into word document.

I have achieved the same functionality in JSP/Java (below is the code), but 
unable to develop the same in Tapestry.

Can you please help me so that I can develop the same functionality in 
Tapestry 4.

```
<body>  
<%  
    String exportToWord;  
    exportToWord = request.getParameter("exportToWord");  
    if (exportToWord != null &&  exportToWord.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("YES")){
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-word"); 
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;
    filename="+"word.doc");}
%>  
This is the plain text.<p><i>This is the italic text. </i>  
<p><b>This is the old text. </b>    
<p><s>This is the strike text.</s>
<p><font color="green">This is he color text. </font> 
<p><a href="#">This is hyperlink. </a>
<p><%if exportToWord == null) {%><a href="word.jsp?exportToWord=YES">Export to word</a> 
<%}%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you are using Tapestry 5 then you follow the below link as in our project we are using the old version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520097/file-download-link-in-tapestry

Comment: yeehaaah cowboy!!! that's some really hacky JSP you have there!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to send html and pretend it's a word document? You are much better off using something like [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org) to generate proper document.

The 'tapestry way' of doing this is by returning a [StreamResponse](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/StreamResponse.html) from a component action (or from a page's onActivate() event). Some documentation [here](http://tapestry.apache.org/page-navigation.html). See [here](http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com/pdflinkdemo) for an example which downloads a dynamically generated pdf.

If you really want to send the page html as a document, you could use something like [tapestry-stitch capture](http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com/capturedemo) or [tapestry-offline](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-offline) to render a page/component to a string. I think this is really hacky.

Comment: These document are of Tapestry 5 and i am working on Tapestry 4. For Tapestry 5 i have already found the way to solve my query (please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520097/file-download-link-in-tapestry), it would be really grateful if you can suggest some solution in Tapestry 4.